# Atmosphere with Spring Security

Tags: gwt, spring-security, websocket, comet, atmosphere

I asked this question, but no answers. I found a lot of discussion about it. But no real solutions.
That's what I see.
After the first puch from server to client I receive data on client but Spring session is lost (I use GWT so all GWT RPC calls - 401 error). If I'm just doing push notifications from client to server without response from the server, the session is not lost.

More details [here](http://alex.66705.x6.nabble.com/Atmosphere-with-Spring-Security-for-GWT-app-td2.html)

If someone faced with the integration of Atmosphere and Spring Security (not necessarily with GWT). Please write. Or if someone has a good experience GWT + Spring Security + any other comet\websocket framework please share your experience.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you can try [enabling HTTP session support](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Enabling-HttpSession-Support). If you can get to the underlying HTTP session, you should have access to `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`.